# Get entries in an entry type in twig template

Tags: craft3, entries, sections

I have two channel types section namely "Services" and "Cases". I have added caseServices as entry field in cases. I can get services of a case in twig as entry.caseServices. But how can i get cases where a particular service used to show on service page ?

[image: Image preview]

Answer (score 2):

You can do an entry query with the type parameter:

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#type

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().section('channelName').type('typeName').all() %}
```

Or expressed without chaining and possibly better readability without having new lines for each parameter.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'channelName',
    type: 'typeName'
}).all() %}
```

Comment: Let suppose i have a case named "Case 1" in which i can select "service 1" and "service 2", which are services entries. I can get these services on "case 1" details page but how i  can get "case 1" when i go to "service 1" or "service 2" page ? Please reply i need it as soon as possible. 

I can guess it will be done using relatedTo but im not able to create such element query in twig file.